# Assign type 'date' to a field in fluentd record transformer

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluent

Hi I have a fluentd config setup to filter logs sent to ElasticSearch. I have a field 'TIME' which is created from an existing field but that is shown as 'unknown' type in Elastic Search. I like t make it of type 'date' since i need to sort it accordingly. My config:

```
<filter docker>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
   TIME ${record["MESSAGE"].scan(/\d+-\d+-\d+\ \d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+/).last}
  </record>  
</filter>
```

The value in MESSAGE can be something like:

```
2021-03-31 12:12:05.856 LOG     : Message <checked [abc]>
```

I extract the first part as TIME, which works fine except that it is of type 'unknown' when shown in Elastic Search. Is there a way to assign 'date' type to this field. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this already

```
      auto_typecast true
```

you can put it under "enable_ruby true" for example